# How to implement a Java application which automatically updates based on Maven?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I'm developing a Rich-client Java application and need a feature to do auto update when a new version is available.

I'm using maven for the build. By its own, the maven-dependency-plugin could copy and download dependencies for a given POM. The only problem is how to integrate this inside a Java application.

Has anyone tried this before?

Comment: It seems quite odd. Maven is a tool for managing a project during the development. You may try adding a POM to your final app, following the Maven folder structure, and setup a regularly task to call a Maven command to force the download of the jars.
A better solution would be the use of a embedded Maven. In any case, it would mean struggle with Maven and its configuration.

Comment: It also means making Maven part of the application stack which you are building using Maven... that would not be my choice of implementing an auto-update feature, a simple HTTP call to some web server is enough.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are speaking about library/jar(dependency). In that case you remove the version. Hence by default maven takes the latest version. But in real scenario, when you move from one version to another version, a regression testing is required because some changes in a version may not work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what kind of application you have or whether you need maven to do this task. First of all, you need to check if there is a newer version available or not. If the there answer if yes, your listener will trigger your updateApplication(assume you name it like this) method. Your method than download the required jars, files or etc.. to appropriated places, replacing the old ones. But like I said, I don't know your architecture, it may not be suitable for every case.

Comment: You will also need to write either a custom ClassLoader that will allow you to replace classes on the fly (I think this is dangerous), or some method of cycling the app so it picks up the new classes (what I see most applications do).

Comment: CodeChimp you're right, but as i said, it was only an assumption, with no knowledge about the architecture. You can also try to use OSGI.

Comment: I think OSGI would be the best bet long term if this app intends to live for a long while.  I looked at it once, though, and most of it went well over my head.

Answer (score 0):

For client side you can just write a method which checks for updates after starting an app.

Answer (score 0):

Maven is a configuration management and deployment tool.
You need a runtime solution instead of build / compile time.
If you have a maven repository central, you should have a downloader to retrieve the latest version from it.
For example you can find some scripts how to download an artifact from nexus.
Nexus has an own rest api which you can use for it.
It is just a tip.